# Connect Apache server ubuntu to WAN

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, apache2, internet

I am running an Apache 2.4 server in Ubuntu 14.04. MY DSL modem is connected to TP Link router. Thus, my system is connected to interent through wifi.

**ifconfig** provides the local ip **aaa.aaa.a.aaa**. The default gateway to login into the router's settings is **192.168.0.1** .

My aim is to send and receive files from an **android** device to the Apache server from a network outside the router's. Thus, following some tutorials, I set the **port forwarding** at port **80** with the ip as **aaa.aaa.a.aaa**.

The **WAN** ip displayed at the router settings page is **bbb.bbb.b.b**, while the public ip obtained by googling **what is my ip** is **ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc** .

I edited my **/etc/hosts** file to include the ip **bbb.bbb.b.b** with the site name along side. After this setting, I was able to access the server within my **LAN** sonnection, (i.e.) connecting my android device to the same router.

Now, I changed the ip in **/etc/hosts** file to **ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc** and when I try the same from a network outside the router's connection, it doesn't work. Can you please point me towards the right direction to make it work from network outside the LAN.?

My doubts lie along these lines:

1. Is this a problem, because the modem and router are 2 different devices?
2. Earlier, I had a Supernet Infocomm Modem, that served as the router as well, and when I tried the same with that, it worked for even networks outside the connection. Currently I have changed my work station and I want to set it up here as well, but am facing the issue as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to touch [`/etc/hosts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) on the server. The contained records serve to connect *other* servers by name, similarly to [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

As you are indicating, the problem is likely caused by separate modem and router. You need to set port forwarding on *all network devices<sup>1)</sup>* sharing the same public IP address<sup>2)</sup> in the path to your server.

1) I mean all devices operating on [network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer) which is the layer of [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) (including IP addresses). Hubs, switches etc. are not affected.

2) *Public* IP address is the address you get when accessing sites like http://whatismyipaddress.com/ from your [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network). [*Private* IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses) are used inside a LAN and usually begin with `10.`, `172.` or `192.168.` A LAN usually shares one public IPv4 address. This technique is called [NAT](http://whatismyipaddress.com/nat).

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by same public ip address? In my case, I get ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc when I search for my ip. Does that mean both my router and modem share the same public ip.?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan When you search for your “outside” (or public) IP address on _any device in your LAN_, you’ll get the same one. This is what I mean by sharing the public IP address. It happens through [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Comment: essentially, I have to setup port forwarding in both my modem and router right?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Yes, I might be speaking too generic. :-)

Comment: Information always helps. Thank you for your time.!